# Retrieving Soundex Codes from a Data Column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

is it possible to make such a query in SQL: there is a column with names, let's say FirstName, you need to get the soundex code for each name in the column and write these codes into the FirstNamesdx column?

Comment: If SOUNDEX() function is implemented in your DBMS then this is possible.

Comment: yes, i have it, but unfortunately I have a problem with creating a query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test_tbl(
             first_name VARCHAR(50),
             FirstNamesdx VARCHAR(50)
                     );

insert into test_tbl(first_name) values ('Earbuds'),
                                        ('Phone'),
                                        ('Charger'),
                                        ('Data Cable'),
                                        ('Speakers');
```

Then you can use an update with the same table to get the needed values:

```
update test_tbl a
inner join 
( select first_name, SOUNDEX(first_name) as soundex_first_name 
  from test_tbl
) as b
on a.first_name=b.first_name
set a.FirstNamesdx=b.soundex_first_name;
```

**You have an easy way:**

```
update test_tbl
set FirstNamesdx= SOUNDEX(first_name);
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pB6b5xrgPKCivFWcpQHsyE/8

Results:
[image]

Comment: Subquery is excess.

Comment: @Akina, yeah `update test_tbl set FirstNamesdx= SOUNDEX(first_name);`. I didn't think about this

Comment: Thank you guys, its working!